# Limit LDAP request to AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is there a way to limit requests from a specific user to the AD such that he can only ask if a username or an email address exists or not? The user should not be able to request other data from the AD.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the default permissions in Active Directory (AD) to accommodate this requirement, but it won't be particularly easy or "clean". The default permissions in AD are, arguably, very "open".

To accomplish what you're looking for you're going to need to enable List Object Mode in your Active Directory (to limit object visibility). You should use a group (rather than a "specific user") to be named in permissions to grant the rights to read email addresses. I think you'll have to do some experimenting to get things to work how you want. (I don't have a scratch AD laying around right now that I'm willing to use to give you step-by-step instructions.)